# How I can read content of the ssh key file using a path read from a file?

Tags: cat, command-substitution

I need to read content of the ssh key using the given path resides in a file like following:
my ssh private key is: `~/.ssh/firstname.lastname`

When I call `cat ~/.ssh/firstname.lastname` in terminal on ubuntu, I get the expected result. However, if I would get the path to my ssh key from any text file, then I get `cat: '~/.ssh/firstname.lastname': No such file or directory`.

For instance, I have `path_to_key.txt` file containing single line `~/.ssh/firstname.lastname`.

So calling `cat $(cat path_to_key.txt)` in terminal returns me error message mentioned above.

All files reside under the same directory and callings happen also from that directory.

Why I can not "cat" in such a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cats all worked, but the tilde (`~`) was not processed like it normally would be on a command-line. The inner `cat` returned the contents of the file, but the outer `cat` had already been processed for tilde expansions, wildcards, variable expansions, etc. Therefore, the outer cat looked for a file by the *literal* name of `~/.ssh/firstname.lastname` instead of the intended `/path/to/your/home/.ssh/firstname.lastname`.

Two options for resolution:

1. Include the absolute path to the file: instead of path_to_key.txt containing `~/.ssh/firstname.lastname`, it would contain (for example) `/home/you/.ssh/firstname.lastname`
2. Wrap the outer `cat` with `eval` so that the resulting command (after the command substitution occurs) is *reprocessed*: `eval cat $(cat path_to_key.txt)`. Note that this bring an extra layer of evaluation, so any redirections or subsequent commands inside that key file are executed -- along with your desired tilde expansion, of course.